# How to share (via network) linux linked content?

Tags: linux, windows, samba, links

I have a director called *Public*.
It's a shared dir in network.
I also have a file *doc.odt* in direcory *docs*
I'd like to share the *doc.odt* file through the link.

I have done this:

```
ln -s ~/docs/doc.odt ~/Public/doc.odt
```

Then I opened nautilus and went to:

```
smb://alef/Public/
```

But the file is not shown.

So, how to share linked content?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `smb://` url didn't work over the network I'm going to assume that Samba isn't configured and running on the machine that is serving out files. If it is, then you might need to try the IP address instead of the NetBIOS name.

Otherwise, you first need to make sure that the computer that will be serving the files is running Samba (since you're accessing it via the 'smb' protocol). You can look at [this documentation](http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Networking/Basic_Samba_Network_File_Sharing) for a very basic how-to on setting that up.

If you're running selinux on the computer you plan to server files from, you might want to look at [this blog post](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/14195.html) regarding the setting up of proper permissions in selinux for Samba to work.

Cheers.

Comment: Samba works, because i see other files under: 'smb://alef/Public/'

Answer (score 0):

You may need to tell Samba to allow following symlinks.

To do so, edit your samba configuration file (probably `/etc/samba/smb.conf`), and set these two option in the `[global]` section :

```
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
```

The first one allows samba to follow symbolic links, and the second one allow it to follow links pointing outside of the shared directory.

More details [here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html#samba2-CHP-8-SECT-1.2).